# please! how to!!! ASYNCIO in RECURSIVE program in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, async-await, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
import time

def recur(depth):
    depth -= 1
    print('recursion in', depth)

    for ea in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        if depth>0:
            recur(depth)

def main():
    recur(8)

start = time.time()
print(f'Time: {time.time() - start:.2f}')
main()

end = time.time()
print(f'Time: {end-start:.2f} sec')
```

The code above is simple mode of my long code,

In my original code, each print() function is fired about 20 seconds after previous print() function in order. If my asyncio works right, as I know, print() functions in depth 1 level should be fired at the same time. But it doesn,t.
how can we use asyncio-python in recursion?

[image]

---

This is print out of simple code above, we can see 2100001000. This means it's not async

[image]

Comment: very similar.. but I think it's not

Comment: You say it "failed." How did it fail? What error did you get? What code did you use? We can't help fix your code if you don't provide those details.

Comment: there wasnt error. it just does not work async way.  If you know well about this, please show.